# OpenGL lines drawn on top of gluSphere's?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been experimenting with OpenGL, trying to draw spheres inside and outside of rectangular prisms. The problem is, no matter where I choose to draw the spheres, the grid is always laid on top of my circles, as can be seen below:

[image: My OpenGL window]

What I am doing right now is basically using `glTranslatef` to initially translate everything 100 units in the negative z direction, then using `GL_LINE_STRIP` to draw the lines that make up the prism, and finally using `glTranslatef` and `glusphere` to create the circles. The prism is supposed to extend from -50 to 0 on the z axis, and the sphere nearer the middle is supposed to be located at (30, 30, 0), while the sphere near the corner is supposed to be located at (50, 50, 5).

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you call `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` in your rendering function ?

Comment: Hm, I added `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` to the beginning of my `glutDisplayFunc` and now my window is empty. What does this mean?

Comment: Yay I did it! `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` Thanks a lot for your help!